# Hyperledger Fabric: use mobile and web as peers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I would like to create a hybrid mobile/web application and one of the key concept of it is user anonymity. I want it to have channels where **peers** are web or mobile clients, owned by other people, like you, your sister/brother — owned by end users (it's not my own or other's organisations hardware like it is described in fabric documentation).

I want those clients to have own copies of ledgers (e.g. at least last 100k entries of that ledger), also want them them to validate transactions and restrict operations if they detect some anomaly. In other words, I want them to create self-driven society, ruled by blockchain platform.

How it could be implemented in Hyperledger Fabric? What components/architecture are suited best for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger is not an anonymous platform. Every org which makes up the network needs to have peers in order to function and they all require installation and hardware to run on.

Someone needs to maintain the network and someone needs to cover the expense of doing that.

so,

1. it's not anonymous, every participant is clearly identified via an identity which is backed by a certificate, issued by an admin.
2. it's not free to run and maintain.

the concept of private data does exist but not at participant / user level. It's at org level. If you want to read more, here's a link to get you started : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html

Comment: do you know some solutions to build IoT blockchain network on mobile and web platforms? Let's forget about anonymity. It's ok if all contracts will be public, but I hope to connect mobiles/desktops in one network